# Tuleap Agile Dashboard Drag & Drop not working

Tags: virtualbox, dashboard, tuleap

**I'm using the TuleapAppliance.6.11 and already tested 6.5 - 6.11**. All of theses Versions have the same problem in my VM's:

Agile Dashboard seems to work (Import from Dashboard & Trackers from Template XML) but Planning view with Drag & Drop functionlity is not working.

The mouse hover appears but after click nothing happens. (Tested in Chrome & Firefox = no console Outputs/Errors)

**Can someone pls give me a hint how to fix that?** It must be something depending on the applicance and moving it/importing it in my virtual box. Because on https://demo-tuleap.enalean.com/ everthing works fine.

Comment: found something i will try on monday https://tuleap.net/plugins/forumml/message.php?group_id=101&topic=27573&list=1

Comment: It Works! removing the /usr/share/tuleap/src/www/script/combined/*.js file forces to auto. regen. that file from tuleap.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Disk size is very small on the appliance, it might be a disk space issue

Answer (score 0):

This is the right solution and i test it and it working.
  step 1: cd /usr/share/codendi/src/scipts/combind/
  step 2: rm *js